# Jmeter - How to capture curl manpage parameters for http request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to create a report in Jmeter where I am fetching a file from URL and in report I need to capture following information -

```
DNS resolution (time_namelookup)
Connect (time_connect)
TLS handshake (time_appconnect)
HTTP request start (time_pretransfer)
HTTP response start (time_starttransfer)
HTTP response completed (time_total)
```

I am able to capture these using following command from my Mac's terminal.

curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "https:///large5-1663346153.bmp"
here's the content of curl-format.txt file

```
time_namelookup:  %{time_namelookup}s\n
time_connect:  %{time_connect}s\n
time_appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}s\n
time_pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}s\n
time_redirect:  %{time_redirect}s\n
time_starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}s\n
----------\n
time_total:  %{time_total}s\n
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) JMeter can report the following metrics:

- Connect time
- Latency [(time to first byte](https://web.dev/ttfb/))
- Elapsed time (time to last byte)

The only way to get the metrics you're looking for in JMeter is executing the curl command via [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) or [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) and get the values from the response using suitable [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)